# How to send email automatically using task scheduler using PHP and mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, email, scheduled-tasks

I want to send a reminder email to perticular email id.Reminder date and time are stored in mysql database.When reminder date and time = current date and time, that time i need to send a email that says You have new reminder with tha remarks(remarks is the database column).How to do this plz help me.

I am using windows8 need to use Task scheduler. by giving the script/program

Comment: please let me know is there anyway to do this

Comment: use Laravel scheduler and linux cronjob/windows task scheduler

Answer (score -1):

You can use cron job to send automatic mail function.

also refer
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/managing-cron-jobs-with-php--net-19428

Comment: cant able to do in taskscheduler?

Comment: sry. didnt get ur question.

Comment: in windows, sheduler Task option is there know

Comment: using shedulertaks,we can run a php  script